# Как изменить размер наложения одного изображения на другое?

Tags: php, opencart

В стандартном функционале OpenCart есть функция наложения watermark

```
    public function watermark($watermark, $position = 'bottomright') {
    switch($position) {
        case 'topleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
        case 'topcenter':
            $watermark_pos_x = intval(($this->width - $watermark->getWidth()) / 2);
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
        case 'topright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->width - $watermark->getWidth();
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
        case 'middleleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = intval(($this->height - $watermark->getHeight()) / 2);
            break;
        case 'middlecenter':
            $watermark_pos_x = intval(($this->width - $watermark->getWidth()) / 2);
            $watermark_pos_y = intval(($this->height - $watermark->getHeight()) / 2);
            break;
        case 'middleright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->width - $watermark->getWidth();
            $watermark_pos_y = intval(($this->height - $watermark->getHeight()) / 2);
            break;
        case 'bottomleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->height - $watermark->getHeight();
            break;
        case 'bottomcenter':
            $watermark_pos_x = intval(($this->width - $watermark->getWidth()) / 2);
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->height - $watermark->getHeight();
            break;
        case 'bottomright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->width - $watermark->getWidth();
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->height - $watermark->getHeight();
            break;
    }
    imagealphablending( $this->image, true );
    imagesavealpha( $this->image, true );
    imagecopy($this->image, $watermark->getImage() , $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, $watermark->getWidth(), $watermark->getHeight());

    imagedestroy($watermark->getImage());
}
```

При ее использовании изображение накладывается очень маленьким, где можно изменить размер watermark в Opencart или как отредактировать эту функцию, чтобы изображение накладывалось на всю область изображения ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `\catalog\model\tool\image.php`:

```
if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
    $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
    $image->resize($width, $height);
    $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
```

Замените на:

```
if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
    $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
    $image->resize($width, $height);
    $image->watermark(new Image(DIR_IMAGE . 'ваша_водянка.png'), 'ваш_позишн');
    $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
```

Так `watermark` будет накладываться на всё изображение товара (учитывая пропорции, естессно). Не забудьте удалить/почистить папку `image/cache`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос состоял немного в другом,
вне зависимости от размера водяного знака он накладывается одного размера , нужно чтобы изображение водяного знака он растягивал по всей площади картинки

Comment: Вы решение пробовали применить в ваше коде?

Comment: Да,
ваш код добавляет два водяного знака,
 + `$image_wm` не определена
`$new_image, $old_image` должны быть `$image_old`

Comment: В ответе было одно лишнее наложение - убрал. И добавил скрин, как выводит (на скрине водянка - лого опенкарта)

Comment: Какая у вас версия Opencart,
в моем случае  получается goo.gl/TCWrMv
Причем такое происходит не везде , только изображений продукта

Comment: версия не имеет значения в ветке 2.х. Основной момент здесь - наложение водянки должно происходить после $image->resize.

Comment: Все спасибо, понял
Правда с квадратными изображениями  ,если watermark прямоугольный не совсем корректно работает,
тогда уж над чтобы он выставлял по ширине изображения размер ватермарка
goo.gl/ZM5div

Comment: ёр биг велкам .